# iOS iPhone Device Stats

Tags: ios

Is there a component/control/class I can use to collect device stats about an iPhone / iPad
**I realize that there are multiple API's available to accomplish this** - Is there a class that will do that for me

In Particular I am interested in stats like -

UDID: 
Device Name: 
System Name:
System Version: 6.0
Platform: iPhone 5
Hardware Model: N41AP
Processors: 2
CPU Frequency: 0 Hz
Bus Frequency: 0 Hz
Physical Memory: 1 GB
Non-Kernel Memory: 872.95 MB
Model: iPhone
Localized Model: iPhone
Language: en
Locale: en_US
Capacity: 32 GB
Formatted: 28.08 GB
Used: 13.48 GB
Free: 14.6 GB
Battery State: Charging
Battery Level: 70%
Local IP:
MAC Address:

Answer (score 0):

All this is possible, but big part of this is ilegal. Apple will reject your app if you try to detect MAC Address for example. However, you can play with private frameworks who will provide you all this info.

Comment: I do not want to use private frameworks.  I want the capability during the development phase of the app so that the testers can send me their device information.

Also - The MAC Address is actually displayed by approved apps - Please see the App UDID - So i don't think it is "illegal"